# Google Chrome Crashes Every-time I close a tab with a YouTube video open

Tags: youtube, google-chrome

Lately I have been having an issue. Whenever I close a open tab in Google Chrome which has a YouTube video open in it, it crashes. The browser just freezes and then a window pops up saying Google Chrome has stopped responding.

I've heard that sometimes adobe flash player can mess things up so I tried uninstalling it but that didn't fix it. This only started happening a few days ago and I didn't change anything except now I tried using the beta version of Google Chrome to see if it was fixed.

General info:

- Windows 7 64 Bit
- Latest Google Chrome Beta Version.

If anyone knows the issue your help would be greatly appreciated. (caches and history was cleared already tried it)

Comment: This is an issue with a web browser, and so really should have been on [su].

Comment: @AlEverett the issue itself was based around YouTube though and that was what was triggering the issue, thus the question was asked here. It may have turned out that it just happened to be YouTube that was triggering it, but the original question was relating to YouTube (a web app) triggering an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I have done some research and found that this is a known issue and the Google team was able to reproduce the issue and is working on a fix. See [Help Forum Article](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?hl=en&tid=1fe8d66c8677d694).

In case you don't want to wait for the fix to be implemented into the normal Google Chrome Build you can try [Google Canary](http://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs). Fixed it for me! Google Canary operates as a secondary browser, so you can have Google Chrome and Google Canary both installed and running at the same time it will not overwrite the old one like Google Chrome Beta does.

Edit: It's awesome to see the YouTube/Chrome team working to fix the issue! The issue has now been fixed according to another Answer they have made on the Help Forums. [Crash Fixed Help Forum Link](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=1fe8d66c8677d694&hl=en&fid=1fe8d66c8677d6940004b7c53492d78c&hltp=2)

Comment: I was having this problem too. I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: @stevether It's been fixed now so you can switch back to the regular Google Chrome now!

Comment: But Canary is shiny and new!

Comment: @stevether True I guess.